# Grid - change entire row background color based on values on one column?

Tags: grid-layouts

Given a matrix defined through `Grid`, how can I specify the background color of entire rows based of the values of the cell in a specific column? For example, I have the following matrix:

```
 matrix = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 4}];
 Grid[matrix, Frame-> All];

{"0", "2", "5", "7"},
{"6", "2", "7", "1"},
{"0", "9", "10", "8"},
{"7", "2", "6", "5"},
{"6", "8", "10", "3"}
```

and I want to set a background color for the rows which are containing values bigger than 6 on the 3rd column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SeedRandom[420];
matrix = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 4}];
colorrules = Table[n -> If[matrix[[n, 3]] < 6, Gray, Pink], {n, 1, 5}];
Grid[matrix, Frame -> All, Background -> {None, colorrules}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Could you explain me the meaning of "& /@ Range[5]?

Comment: @Conrad - there I was using a pure function (the `#` and `&` symbols) and `Map`ping that pure function (the `/@` notation) onto the list `{1,2,3,4,5}` (the `Range[5]`).  I was trying to write it shorter than `Table[n -> If[matrix[[n, 3]] < 6, Gray, Pink], {n, 1, 5}]` but I think it's easier to use the `Table` and more clear so I will change it.

Answer (score 1):

```
matrix = RandomInteger[{0, 10}, {5, 4}];

Grid[matrix, 
Background -> {None, 
DeleteCases[
Table[Which[matrix[[i, 3]] > 6, i -> Red], {i, 1, 
Length[matrix]}], Null]}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]