# Grid: different background color (of row) based on values

Tags: grid-layouts

I want to use `Grid` to tabulate the following `list` and have the same background color for rows of the same value on column 4. 
The actual `list` is very long.

```
list=
{{1, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 0, -1, 1}, 4.48},
 {2, {-2, -1, -1}, {-1, 0, 1, -1}, 4.48},
 {3, {2, 1, 1}, {1, 0, -1, 1}, 4.48},
 {4, {-2, -1, -1}, {-1, 0, 1, -1}, 4.48},
 {9, {-2, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1, 1}, 4.48},
 {10, {2, 1, -1}, {1, 0, -1, -1}, 4.48},
 {11, {2, 1, -1}, {1, 0, -1, -1}, 4.48},
 {12, {-2, -1, 1}, {-1, 0, 1, 1}, 4.48},
 {5, {0, -1, 0}, {1, -2, 1, 0}, 5.266},
 {6, {0, -1, 0}, {1, -2, 1, 0}, 5.266},
 {7, {0, 1, 0}, {-1, 2, -1, 0}, 5.266},
 {8, {0, 1, 0}, {-1, 2, -1, 0}, 5.266},
 {5, {1, -4, 0}, {2, -3, 1, 0}, 5.6323},
 {6, {1, -4, 0}, {2, -3, 1, 0}, 5.6323},
 {7, {-1, 4, 0}, {-2, 3, -1, 0}, 5.6323},
 {8, {-1, 4, 0}, {-2, 3, -1, 0}, 5.6323}}
```

I found a solution to a similar question [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/116069/34223). I wonder how can I build the `colorrules` elegantly. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a solution with `Item[...]` :

```
itemRules = 
  With[{color = RandomColor[]},
    (x : {___, #}) :>  (Item[#,Background -> color] & /@ x)] & /@ Union[list[[All, 4]]];

Grid[list /. itemRules, Dividers -> All]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
sets = GatherBy[Transpose[{Range[Length[list]], list[[All, 4]]}], #[[2]] &];
colors = {LightYellow, LightOrange, LightBlue};
colorrules = 
 Flatten@Table[
   Thread[sets[[n, All, 1]] -> colors[[n]]], {n, Length[sets]}];

Grid[list, Frame -> All, Background -> {None, colorrules}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Using [`Association`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Association.html) and [`Lookup`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Lookup.html) to specify row backgrounds:

```
keys = Union @ list[[All, -1]];
colors = Lighter @* Lighter @* ColorData["Rainbow"] /@ Rescale[keys];
backgroundColors = AssociationThread[keys, colors];

Legended[Grid[list,  Frame -> All, 
  Background -> {None, Lookup[list[[All, -1]]] @ backgroundColors}],
 SwatchLegend[colors, keys]]
```

[image]